# 301 Redirect to relative path using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'd like to be able to 301 redirect any requests made to:

```
http://example.com/foo
```

To:

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/dashboard
```

The trouble is, this `.htaccess` file can be 'installed' on any domain in any directory so I wont know the absolute URL.

I've tried using a relative URL or the `HTTP_HOST` variable but they don't work as expected.

I need to use a 301 because I need the user to be able to identify that they're on the dashboard via the URL in their address bar.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It will not work if the `.htaccess` is not placed inside the root or `foo` folder of the domain in question. Why? Because, if its not on either of the mentioned folders it will not allow you to perform the redirection.

Comment: So if URL is `http://example.com/foo/abc/123` then it will be redirected to `http://example.com/foo/abc/123/bar/dashboard` ?

Comment: @Prix thanks for the info, I feared that. Maybe I can get away with doing a regular rewrite to /bar/index.php?view=dashboard and then set a location header based on the view parameter.

Comment: @user3325134 why would the `.htaccess` be on any possible folder is what I don't understand why not a single `.htaccess` at the root is there a reason for that? Or even multilevel `.htaccess` pertinent to their directory. Maybe if you give better examples and tell us if you're using a CMS or more about your situation we might be able to give you a solution. But right now what you said is pretty vague specially on how the `.htaccess` is or can be placed.

Comment: Besides .htaccess is created manually not by a code that one cannot control paths or base.

Comment: Because what if you wanted to use the same .htaccess file on your development environment as on your production server.  In development, all the site files might be in `/Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite` and I might want `/localhost/mysite/foo/abc/123` to map to `/localhost/mysite/foo/bar/dashboard/abc/123` and similarly have `http://example.com/foo/abc/123` map to `http://example.com/foo/bar/dashboard/abc/123` by placing a single file in the mysite directory.